error 2147942402 (0x80070002) when launching `ubuntu2404.exe' error while launching ubuntu in terminal windows
Recently I downloaded Ubuntu- 24.04 LTS on my Windows PC through terminal wsl --install -d Ubuntu-24.04. It downloaded successfully, and then it launched with an error:
error 2147942402 (0x80070002) when launching `ubuntu2404.exe'` 


Screenshot
Settings

I searched for this problem I found this
similar AU question.
I did everything that the answers mentioned but nothing happened.
I also checked my files and I found that C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps here is ubuntu2404.exe but its size is 0KB.

File manager screenshot

An interesting observation is that when I try to run wsl command it returns
Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore

However, when I try to to run wsl --install it returned:
Windows Subsystem for Linux is already installed.


Screenshot

Any solution?

Try adding this path %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps to your system PATH environment variable

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Welcome to AU!  At first glance, I agree with your possible solution (and I've upvoted) but I also agree with the above comment. From the link in the comment above - "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." - If there's any detail you can provide on why you expect this to work, that could be useful. Also explaining how to add the path correctly would also help improve the answer. Thanks!
